# rdflib : ParseException: Expected {SelectQuery | ConstructQuery | DescribeQuery | AskQuery}, found 's' (at char 17), (line:2, col:17)

Tags: python, sparql, rdflib

Working on several SPARQL queries that works, we are facing an issue with the rdflib library, with queries containing projection with *str* function.

Here is an example of code on which the parser fail :

```
query = """
SELECT DISTINCT str(?s) 
WHERE { ?s ?p ?o. }
"""
parsedQuery = rdflib.plugins.sparql.parser.parseQuery(query)
```

the error is :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParseException                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-30dec35045be> in <module>
      3 WHERE { ?s ?p ?o. }
      4 """
----> 5 parsedQuery = rdflib.plugins.sparql.parser.parseQuery(query)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rdflib/plugins/sparql/parser.py in parseQuery(q)
   1058 
   1059     q = expandUnicodeEscapes(q)
-> 1060     return Query.parseString(q, parseAll=True)
   1061 
   1062 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseString(self, instring, parseAll)
   1945             else:
   1946                 # catch and re-raise exception from here, clears out pyparsing internal stack trace
-> 1947                 raise exc
   1948         else:
   1949             return tokens

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseString(self, instring, parseAll)
   1935             instring = instring.expandtabs()
   1936         try:
-> 1937             loc, tokens = self._parse(instring, 0)
   1938             if parseAll:
   1939                 loc = self.preParse(instring, loc)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1836                 ParserElement.packrat_cache_stats[MISS] += 1
   1837                 try:
-> 1838                     value = self._parseNoCache(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1839                 except ParseBaseException as pe:
   1840                     # cache a copy of the exception, without the traceback

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1675             if self.mayIndexError or preloc >= len(instring):
   1676                 try:
-> 1677                     loc, tokens = self.parseImpl(instring, preloc, doActions)
   1678                 except IndexError:
   1679                     raise ParseException(instring, len(instring), self.errmsg, self)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)
   4050                     raise ParseSyntaxException(instring, len(instring), self.errmsg, self)
   4051             else:
-> 4052                 loc, exprtokens = e._parse(instring, loc, doActions)
   4053             if exprtokens or exprtokens.haskeys():
   4054                 resultlist += exprtokens

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1836                 ParserElement.packrat_cache_stats[MISS] += 1
   1837                 try:
-> 1838                     value = self._parseNoCache(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1839                 except ParseBaseException as pe:
   1840                     # cache a copy of the exception, without the traceback

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1675             if self.mayIndexError or preloc >= len(instring):
   1676                 try:
-> 1677                     loc, tokens = self.parseImpl(instring, preloc, doActions)
   1678                 except IndexError:
   1679                     raise ParseException(instring, len(instring), self.errmsg, self)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)
   4250             if maxException is not None:
   4251                 maxException.msg = self.errmsg
-> 4252                 raise maxException
   4253             else:
   4254                 raise ParseException(instring, loc, "no defined alternatives to match", self)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)
   4235         for e in self.exprs:
   4236             try:
-> 4237                 ret = e._parse(instring, loc, doActions)
   4238                 return ret
   4239             except ParseException as err:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1836                 ParserElement.packrat_cache_stats[MISS] += 1
   1837                 try:
-> 1838                     value = self._parseNoCache(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1839                 except ParseBaseException as pe:
   1840                     # cache a copy of the exception, without the traceback

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1675             if self.mayIndexError or preloc >= len(instring):
   1676                 try:
-> 1677                     loc, tokens = self.parseImpl(instring, preloc, doActions)
   1678                 except IndexError:
   1679                     raise ParseException(instring, len(instring), self.errmsg, self)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)
   4443     def parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions=True):
   4444         if self.expr is not None:
-> 4445             return self.expr._parse(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False)
   4446         else:
   4447             raise ParseException("", loc, self.errmsg, self)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1836                 ParserElement.packrat_cache_stats[MISS] += 1
   1837                 try:
-> 1838                     value = self._parseNoCache(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1839                 except ParseBaseException as pe:
   1840                     # cache a copy of the exception, without the traceback

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1675             if self.mayIndexError or preloc >= len(instring):
   1676                 try:
-> 1677                     loc, tokens = self.parseImpl(instring, preloc, doActions)
   1678                 except IndexError:
   1679                     raise ParseException(instring, len(instring), self.errmsg, self)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)
   4050                     raise ParseSyntaxException(instring, len(instring), self.errmsg, self)
   4051             else:
-> 4052                 loc, exprtokens = e._parse(instring, loc, doActions)
   4053             if exprtokens or exprtokens.haskeys():
   4054                 resultlist += exprtokens

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1836                 ParserElement.packrat_cache_stats[MISS] += 1
   1837                 try:
-> 1838                     value = self._parseNoCache(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1839                 except ParseBaseException as pe:
   1840                     # cache a copy of the exception, without the traceback

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1675             if self.mayIndexError or preloc >= len(instring):
   1676                 try:
-> 1677                     loc, tokens = self.parseImpl(instring, preloc, doActions)
   1678                 except IndexError:
   1679                     raise ParseException(instring, len(instring), self.errmsg, self)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)
   4250             if maxException is not None:
   4251                 maxException.msg = self.errmsg
-> 4252                 raise maxException
   4253             else:
   4254                 raise ParseException(instring, loc, "no defined alternatives to match", self)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)
   4235         for e in self.exprs:
   4236             try:
-> 4237                 ret = e._parse(instring, loc, doActions)
   4238                 return ret
   4239             except ParseException as err:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1836                 ParserElement.packrat_cache_stats[MISS] += 1
   1837                 try:
-> 1838                     value = self._parseNoCache(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1839                 except ParseBaseException as pe:
   1840                     # cache a copy of the exception, without the traceback

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1675             if self.mayIndexError or preloc >= len(instring):
   1676                 try:
-> 1677                     loc, tokens = self.parseImpl(instring, preloc, doActions)
   1678                 except IndexError:
   1679                     raise ParseException(instring, len(instring), self.errmsg, self)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)
   4678         if check_ender:
   4679             try_not_ender(instring, loc)
-> 4680         loc, tokens = self_expr_parse(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False)
   4681         try:
   4682             hasIgnoreExprs = (not not self.ignoreExprs)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1836                 ParserElement.packrat_cache_stats[MISS] += 1
   1837                 try:
-> 1838                     value = self._parseNoCache(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1839                 except ParseBaseException as pe:
   1840                     # cache a copy of the exception, without the traceback

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1675             if self.mayIndexError or preloc >= len(instring):
   1676                 try:
-> 1677                     loc, tokens = self.parseImpl(instring, preloc, doActions)
   1678                 except IndexError:
   1679                     raise ParseException(instring, len(instring), self.errmsg, self)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)
   4443     def parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions=True):
   4444         if self.expr is not None:
-> 4445             return self.expr._parse(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False)
   4446         else:
   4447             raise ParseException("", loc, self.errmsg, self)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1836                 ParserElement.packrat_cache_stats[MISS] += 1
   1837                 try:
-> 1838                     value = self._parseNoCache(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1839                 except ParseBaseException as pe:
   1840                     # cache a copy of the exception, without the traceback

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1675             if self.mayIndexError or preloc >= len(instring):
   1676                 try:
-> 1677                     loc, tokens = self.parseImpl(instring, preloc, doActions)
   1678                 except IndexError:
   1679                     raise ParseException(instring, len(instring), self.errmsg, self)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)
   4443     def parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions=True):
   4444         if self.expr is not None:
-> 4445             return self.expr._parse(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False)
   4446         else:
   4447             raise ParseException("", loc, self.errmsg, self)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1836                 ParserElement.packrat_cache_stats[MISS] += 1
   1837                 try:
-> 1838                     value = self._parseNoCache(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1839                 except ParseBaseException as pe:
   1840                     # cache a copy of the exception, without the traceback

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1675             if self.mayIndexError or preloc >= len(instring):
   1676                 try:
-> 1677                     loc, tokens = self.parseImpl(instring, preloc, doActions)
   1678                 except IndexError:
   1679                     raise ParseException(instring, len(instring), self.errmsg, self)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)
   4250             if maxException is not None:
   4251                 maxException.msg = self.errmsg
-> 4252                 raise maxException
   4253             else:
   4254                 raise ParseException(instring, loc, "no defined alternatives to match", self)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)
   4235         for e in self.exprs:
   4236             try:
-> 4237                 ret = e._parse(instring, loc, doActions)
   4238                 return ret
   4239             except ParseException as err:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1836                 ParserElement.packrat_cache_stats[MISS] += 1
   1837                 try:
-> 1838                     value = self._parseNoCache(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1839                 except ParseBaseException as pe:
   1840                     # cache a copy of the exception, without the traceback

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1675             if self.mayIndexError or preloc >= len(instring):
   1676                 try:
-> 1677                     loc, tokens = self.parseImpl(instring, preloc, doActions)
   1678                 except IndexError:
   1679                     raise ParseException(instring, len(instring), self.errmsg, self)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)
   4443     def parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions=True):
   4444         if self.expr is not None:
-> 4445             return self.expr._parse(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False)
   4446         else:
   4447             raise ParseException("", loc, self.errmsg, self)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1836                 ParserElement.packrat_cache_stats[MISS] += 1
   1837                 try:
-> 1838                     value = self._parseNoCache(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1839                 except ParseBaseException as pe:
   1840                     # cache a copy of the exception, without the traceback

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1675             if self.mayIndexError or preloc >= len(instring):
   1676                 try:
-> 1677                     loc, tokens = self.parseImpl(instring, preloc, doActions)
   1678                 except IndexError:
   1679                     raise ParseException(instring, len(instring), self.errmsg, self)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)
   4250             if maxException is not None:
   4251                 maxException.msg = self.errmsg
-> 4252                 raise maxException
   4253             else:
   4254                 raise ParseException(instring, loc, "no defined alternatives to match", self)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)
   4235         for e in self.exprs:
   4236             try:
-> 4237                 ret = e._parse(instring, loc, doActions)
   4238                 return ret
   4239             except ParseException as err:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1836                 ParserElement.packrat_cache_stats[MISS] += 1
   1837                 try:
-> 1838                     value = self._parseNoCache(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1839                 except ParseBaseException as pe:
   1840                     # cache a copy of the exception, without the traceback

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1675             if self.mayIndexError or preloc >= len(instring):
   1676                 try:
-> 1677                     loc, tokens = self.parseImpl(instring, preloc, doActions)
   1678                 except IndexError:
   1679                     raise ParseException(instring, len(instring), self.errmsg, self)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)
   4443     def parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions=True):
   4444         if self.expr is not None:
-> 4445             return self.expr._parse(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False)
   4446         else:
   4447             raise ParseException("", loc, self.errmsg, self)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1836                 ParserElement.packrat_cache_stats[MISS] += 1
   1837                 try:
-> 1838                     value = self._parseNoCache(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1839                 except ParseBaseException as pe:
   1840                     # cache a copy of the exception, without the traceback

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1675             if self.mayIndexError or preloc >= len(instring):
   1676                 try:
-> 1677                     loc, tokens = self.parseImpl(instring, preloc, doActions)
   1678                 except IndexError:
   1679                     raise ParseException(instring, len(instring), self.errmsg, self)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)
   4033         # pass False as last arg to _parse for first element, since we already
   4034         # pre-parsed the string as part of our And pre-parsing
-> 4035         loc, resultlist = self.exprs[0]._parse(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False)
   4036         errorStop = False
   4037         for e in self.exprs[1:]:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1836                 ParserElement.packrat_cache_stats[MISS] += 1
   1837                 try:
-> 1838                     value = self._parseNoCache(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1839                 except ParseBaseException as pe:
   1840                     # cache a copy of the exception, without the traceback

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1679                     raise ParseException(instring, len(instring), self.errmsg, self)
   1680             else:
-> 1681                 loc, tokens = self.parseImpl(instring, preloc, doActions)
   1682 
   1683         tokens = self.postParse(instring, loc, tokens)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)
   4443     def parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions=True):
   4444         if self.expr is not None:
-> 4445             return self.expr._parse(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False)
   4446         else:
   4447             raise ParseException("", loc, self.errmsg, self)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1836                 ParserElement.packrat_cache_stats[MISS] += 1
   1837                 try:
-> 1838                     value = self._parseNoCache(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1839                 except ParseBaseException as pe:
   1840                     # cache a copy of the exception, without the traceback

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1679                     raise ParseException(instring, len(instring), self.errmsg, self)
   1680             else:
-> 1681                 loc, tokens = self.parseImpl(instring, preloc, doActions)
   1682 
   1683         tokens = self.postParse(instring, loc, tokens)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)
   2881         if instring[loc] == self.firstMatchChar:
   2882             return loc + 1, self.match
-> 2883         raise ParseException(instring, loc, self.errmsg, self)
   2884 
   2885 _L = Literal

ParseException: Expected {SelectQuery | ConstructQuery | DescribeQuery | AskQuery}, found 's'  (at char 17), (line:2, col:17)
```

It looks like rdflib.plugins.sparql.parser.parseQuery(...) cannot parse it. Or maybe there is something that I missed writing code. If someone can help that would be great.

Comment: that'S invalid SPARQL, expressions have to be put into brackets: `SELECT DISTINCT (str(?s) as ?s_str) 
WHERE { ?s ?p ?o. }`

Comment: Thanks a lot @UninformedUser !
In SelectClause, expressions have to be renamed in any case.

Answer (score 0):

As UninformedUser answered in the comments,

```
SELECT DISTINCT str(?s)
```

needs to be

```
SELECT DISTINCT (str(?s) as ?s_str)
```